# How to fix C-style for statement?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

What is right way to fix **C-style for statement** for the code which is posted below?

Currently I am getting this warring:

> C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>   version of Swift

```
var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs> = nil
if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
    // Warning
    for (var ptr = ifaddr; ptr != nil; ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next) {
        // Do some stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ramis did my answer help you?  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: @JAL Sorry, but I did not have chance to try it as I am busy with other issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could convert the `for` loop into a `while` loop:

```
var ptr = ifaddr
while ptr != nil {
    // Do stuff
    ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that worked for me.

```
var ptr = ifaddr
repeat {
   ptr = ptr.memory.ifa_next
   if ptr != nil {
      ...
   }
} while ptr != nil
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 3 you can use `sequence` for generalized loops, such
as traversing a "linked list". Here:

```
var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
if getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 {
    if let firstAddr = ifaddr {
        for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
}
```