# C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3 (Continuos error)

Tags: ios, arrays, for-loop, swift3

I have had this problem since updating to `Swift 3`. I have tried updating this to `Swift 3` by using `stride(from:to:by:)` but I can't implement the old `Swift 2` code to the `Swift 3` code. Below I have included my code:

```
for var i = 0; i <= self.senderArray.count - 1; i += 1 {

  if self.senderArray[i] == userName {

         self.other2Array.append(self.otherArray[i])
  }
  else {    

     self.other2Array.append(self.senderArray[i])
  }              

  self.message2Array.append(self.messageArray[i])
  self.sender2Array.append(self.senderArray[i])

  }
```

The error I am getting:

> C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3

I have tried this method below, but it doesn't work:

```
for i in 0 ..< self.senderArray.count
```

Before anyone marks this question as a duplicate I have had a look at the following questions but for some reason, I can't figure out how to implement my code into  the updated `Swift 3` code.

[#warning: C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173379/warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-ve)

[How to fix C-style for statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153839/how-to-fix-c-style-for-statement)

[Fix warning "C-style for Statement is deprecated" in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213333/fix-warning-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-in-swift-3)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814867/fix-c-style-for-statement-is-deprecated-in-swift

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to write the `for` loop in Swift 3 and explain what issues you are having with it.

Comment: Did you look at any sample code whatsoever?

Comment: There's no need to use `self.` everywhere; that's just decreasing readability.

Comment: `for i in 0 ..< self.senderArray.count` – as for example demonstrated in your first reference – did not work?

Comment: @MartinR No that did not work

Comment: @Jordan What is the issue you are facing when you tried MartinR's suggestion ?

Comment: @gnasher729. Yes, I do look at sample code, but I just can't figure out why `for i in 0 ..< self.senderArray.count` doesn't work. Nevermind the answer below has fixed my problem. Now I know where I went wrong at least I can read about it!

Comment: @MidhunMP thanks, but the answer below has fixed it 

Comment: *"Now I know where I went wrong"* – I am glad that your problem is solved. Please update your question so that the actual problem becomes apparent not only to you but also for us. Questions without a clear problem statement have no value for future readers of this thread and are off-topic.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for understanding. It all makes sense when someone else points out the problem!

Comment: Sorry, but I did *not* understand your problem, and you did not demonstrate *why* `for i in 0 ..< self.senderArray.count` does not work, and what the actual problem was.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the index is easy with `enumerated`:

```
for (i, sender) in senderArray.enumerated() {
    // Can simply use 'sender' here, no need to index into senderArray.
    if sender == userName {
       ...

    // Unchanged lines; 'i' is used as index here.   
    self.message2Array.append(self.messageArray[i])
    self.sender2Array.append(self.senderArray[i])

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Graham! I see where I went wrong.  Thank you for helping me out!